# Error running npm run dev on my newly created next.js app

Tags: next.js, client

Literally I executed the dashboard example command:

npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-dashboard --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/dashboard/starter-example"

and then "npm run dev" into my repository folder and the follows issues appeared

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUx3P.png)

logs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMlZF.png)

I don't understand this problem because I didn't change anything in the project folder.

I started using a different name for the project and I thought that was the problem because it's an example folder so I used the default name and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my npm version to 20.10 and it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just update your node to the latest version, I had this problem for a long time and now it has stopped occurring.

My current version is v20.11.0.

If you are using nvm, run: `nvm install --lts --latest-npm`